# db2 Why am I getting a "[SQL0802] Data conversion of data mapping error" exception?

Tags: sql, db2

I work on a C# project and i created an sql procedure on Iseries (AS400) and Iam getting the following error.

An error occurred while processing the results. - [SQL0802] Data conversion or data mapping error.

This is the code of sql procedure. Can anyone have an idea to help me with this. The scenario is that the usercode, applicationcategory and isfavorite getting as parameters.

Thanks

```
BEGIN

DECLARE STRING_QUERY VARCHAR ( 2000 ) ;

DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR SQL_STATEMENT ;

IF ISFAVORITE = '0' THEN
SET STRING_QUERY = 'SELECT A.APPLICATIONCATEGORY,C.FOLDEROFPROJECT,' ||

'C.PROJECT,D.PROJECTGRDESCRIPTION,D.PROJECTENDESCRIPTION,' ||

'D.OBJECTNAME,D.OBJECTTYP,' ||

'C.FAVORITE FROM ERPLIB.APPLICATIONDEPARTMENT A ' ||

'INNER JOIN ERPLIB.APPLICATIONUSERDEPARTMENTAUTHIRITY B ' ||

'ON B.USERCODE = ' || P_USERCODE ||

' AND B.APPLICATIONCATEGORY = A.APPLICATIONCATEGORY' ||

' INNER JOIN ERPLIB.APPLICATIONUSERMODULEAUTHORITY C ' ||

'ON C.USERCODE = ' || P_USERCODE ||

' AND C.APPLICATIONCATEGORY = A.APPLICATIONCATEGORY' ||

' AND C.FAVORITE = ''0''' ||

' INNER JOIN ERPLIB.APPLICATIONMODULE D ' ||

'ON D.APPLICATIONCATEGORY = A.APPLICATIONCATEGORY' ||

' AND D.FOLDEROFOBJECT = C.FOLDEROFPROJECT AND ' ||

'D.PROJECT = C.PROJECT ' ||

'WHERE A.APPLICATIONCATEGORY = ''001''' ;

END IF ;


PREPARE SQL_STATEMENT FROM STRING_QUERY ;

OPEN C1 ;

RETURN ;
```

Comment: Which db2-driver are you using on the C# machine? (from IBM or from Microsoft, and which version?) ? What is the operating system on the C# machine and what codepage/language-setting is active for your client? Do you know the codepage of the table/columns on the i-series , and how have you verified that the data values in those columns is compliant with the database codepage? (use the hex() function to examine).

Comment: Hi I found the problem, thanks for your interesting.